# mov instruction doesn't work other way around

Tags: assembly, x86, att

I'm trying to move the characters that are not digit from the char array "buffer" to new array "clean". "buffer" is created by using scanf function.

```
    .section bss
buffer:
    .skip 20
clean:
    .skip 20
```

...

```
if_digit:
    movl    $0, %ebx
cleanloop:  
    movl    $0, %ecx
    movb    buffer(%ebx), %cl
    pushl   %ecx
    call    isdigit     #nonzero if digit.
    addl    $4, %esp
    incl    %ebx
    cmpl    $0, %eax
    jne clean_buffer    #jmp to clean_buffer if digit
    jmp end_cleanloop


clean_buffer:   
    movb    %cl, clean(%ebx)
    jmp     cleanloop

end_cleanloop:
    movb    $0, clean(%ebx) #add null character at the end.     
    pushl   $clean
    call    atoi        #stores atoi value at eax
    addl    $4, %esp
    subl    $4, iIndex  
    pushl   %eax
    jmp     input
```

What's questionable is about these two lines.

```
movb buffer(%ebx), %cl
```

vs

```
movb %cl, clean(%ebx)
```

The first line stores the certain character in buffer to cl. 
However, second line doesn't take any action. Even when I checked with gdb, no value was stored in clean.

Why does mov instruction works in first line, but not in second line?

Comment: `movl $0` + `movb`: that's what `movzx` aka `movzbl buffer(%ebx), %ecx` is for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a mistake with `incl %ebx`.
I increased the index stored in ebx before copying the value.
This line should go after the `movb %cl, clean(%ebx)`.

It DOES work the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

The call to `isdigit` will clobber the `ecx` register.  So the byte that is stored by `movb %cl, clean(%ebx)` is probably not the one read from `buffer`.

You need to either save and restore `ecx`, use a different register that is saved across a function call (`esi` and `edi` are available, although you'd need to preserve them as part of your function entry and exit), or reload the character from `buffer` before storing it in `clean`.

Comment: I checked the possibility that value stored in ecx might be changed after the call with gdb, but it didn't cahnge.